# Renaming x-axis labels in a beanplot

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am using the beanplot function using the following code:

```
library(beanplot)
beanplot(Grainyield~Year*Tmnt,las = 2, 
     data = maize,
     xlab = "Factors Year.Water Treatment ", 
     ylab = "Yield [kg/ha]", 
     col  = list("yellow", "orange", "green", "blue"))

legend("bottomleft", 
   bty="n",
   c("2008","2009","2010","2011"),
   fill = c("yellow", "orange", "green", "blue"))
```

The x-axis labels are incorrect and I have tried to formatting the x-axis labels using the following code, but I keep receiving errors:

```
axis(1, at=2008.1:2011.6, 
labels=c[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it that you need `(` instead of `[` in `labels=c[1,1, ...` ? Correspondingly you'd need `)`.

Comment: please provide dataset for replication

Comment: Sorry - the ) was a mistake when I copied the code.  The data is a CSV file and I am unable to upload documents -  is there a way to share my data with you?

Comment: you could provide a google drive link, for example, or point to a website where I can download it

Comment: Thanks - here is a link to the csv file in Drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15hUefYU-lMjNnItdieGJvcIHP3tdjNe-/view?usp=sharing) and here is the code from R to upload the file:  maize<-read.table("maizeirrigation.csv", header = T, sep = ";", colClasses = c("Year"="factor", "Tmnt"="factor", "Block"="factor")